# Excel VBA - Checking if value of each cell in one range is in another range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have a workbook with current work ticket data updated with new ticket data. I have nested for each loops at the bottom to check for equality in the ticket number. If it finds a match, it is supposed to update some cells with the new data. If that ticket is not already in my list of tickets, it's supposed to add the new ticket to the bottom. What keeps happening is that even for tickets in the spreadsheet, it keeps adding all tickets from newData to the bottom of currentData. I think the problem ultimately lies with the logic in these nested for loops but I can't figure out exactly what I'm doing wrong.

```
Sub getNewData()

Dim newData As Workbook
Dim ndLastRow As Long
Dim currentData As Workbook
Dim cdLastRow As Long
Dim ndRangeToCheck As Range
Dim cdRangeToCheck As Range
Dim ndRow As Long
Dim cdRow As Long

Set newData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\<user>\Documents\newData.xlsx")
Set currentData = ThisWorkbook

' Assign last row and the range to compare for each workbook
newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Range("A2").Select
With ActiveSheet
    ndLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
Set ndRangeToCheck = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Range("A2", Cells(ndLastRow, "A"))

currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Activate
With ActiveSheet
    cdLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With
Set cdRangeToCheck = currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Range("B2", Cells(cdLastRow, "B"))

' Iterate through to compare Incident #s between workbooks
Dim rout As Range
Dim rin As Range
Dim match As Boolean
For Each rout In ndRangeToCheck.Cells
    match = False
    For Each rin In cdRangeToCheck.Cells
        If Cells(rin.Row, rin.Column).Value = Cells(rout.Row, rout.Column).Value Then
            match = True
            ndRow = rout.Row
            cdRow = rin.Row
            currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdRow, "L").Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "D").Value
            currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdRow, "O").Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "F").Value
            currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdRow, "P").Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "G").Value
            currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdRow, "Q").Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "H").Value
            currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdRow, "S").Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "L").Value
            currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdRow, "T").Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "N").Value
            currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Rows(rin.Row).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

            Exit For
        End If
    Next rin

    If match = False Then
        ndRow = rout.Row
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdLastRow, "B").Offset(1, 0).Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "A").Value
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdLastRow, "B").Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "0"
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdLastRow, "L").Offset(1, 0).Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "D").Value
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdLastRow, "O").Offset(1, 0).Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "F").Value
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdLastRow, "P").Offset(1, 0).Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "G").Value
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdLastRow, "Q").Offset(1, 0).Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "H").Value
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdLastRow, "S").Offset(1, 0).Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "L").Value
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdLastRow, "T").Offset(1, 0).Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "N").Value
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdLastRow, "F").Offset(1, 0).Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "C").Value
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdLastRow, "M").Offset(1, 0).Value = newData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(ndRow, "E").Value
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Cells(cdLastRow, "M").Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Rows(cdLastRow).Offset(1, 0).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

        ' Reset cdLastRow
        currentData.Worksheets("Incident List").Activate
        With ActiveSheet
            cdLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        End With
    End If
Next rout

newData.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You do not need two loops. Just one loop to get the values for checking and then you can use `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(cdRangeToCheck, "Value to check") > 0 Then`

Comment: Another option would be to simply store them in a `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fault is in the following line:

```
If Cells(rin.Row, rin.Column).Value = Cells(rout.Row, rout.Column).Value
```

where both `Cells` references point to `currentData` while I guess this is correct for the 1st `Cells` occurrence while the 2nd one should point to `newData`

this is due to the use of `Select`/`Selection` and or `Activate`/`ActiveYYY` methods/objects which is quote prone to loose control over actual referenced workbook/worksheet

you should use fully qualified range references up to its parent workbook

Other than that you can take advantage of using [Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method to avoid loops and ... some little tricks to shorten code down a bit, like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getNewData()
    Dim newData As Worksheet, currentData As Worksheet '<--| use just the worksheets since they are what you actually need to work with
    Dim ndRangeToCheck As Range, cdRangeToCheck As Range '<-- data ranges
    Dim rout As Range, f As Range '<--| helper ranges
    Dim cdRow As Long
    Dim cdAddressStrng As String, ndAddressStrng As String

    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\newData.xlsx"
    Set newData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Incident List") '<--| set just the sheet since it is what you actually need to work with
    Set currentData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Incident List") '<--| set just the sheet since it is what you actually need to work with

    ' Assign last row and the range to compare for each workbook
    With newData
        Set ndRangeToCheck = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With

    With currentData
        Set cdRangeToCheck = .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    End With

    cdAddressStrng = "L|, O|, P|, Q|, S|, T|"
    ndAddressStrng = "D|, F|, G|, H|, L|, N|"

    ' Iterate through to compare Incident #s between workbooks
    For Each rout In ndRangeToCheck
        Set f = cdRangeToCheck.Find(What:=rout.value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False) '<--| look for the "new" value into current data
        If f Is Nothing Then '<--| if not found...
            cdRow = currentData.Cells(currentData.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row + 1 '<--| ...retrieve current data first empty row
        Else '<--| otherwise...
            cdRow = f.row '<--| ......retrieve found cell row index
        End If
        currentData.Range(Replace(cdAddressStrng, "|", cdRow)).value = newData.Range(Replace(ndAddressStrng, "|", rout.row)).value
        currentData.Rows(cdRow).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Next rout

    newData.Parent.Close '<--| close newdata workbook: since newData is a worksheet we need to "climb up" to its parent workbook
End Sub
```

Comment: @mdperez: did you get through it?